# Import transaction history to new wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I imported old addresses to a new wallet, in order to isolate them.
These addresses are empty, but they had several transactions years ago.
Problem is, these transactions are not showing up in the new wallet.
How do I import the transaction history of these specific addresses to the new wallet?

Comment: I assume you imported the addresses to Bitcoin Core, given the tag you choose. Did you `rescan` after importing?